# Not having to repeat script every time in loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have the following script that happens within a loop. How would I make it so I only have to place it once at the bottom of a page and not have the classes hard coded in? The script occurs for each `<li>` which seems very clunky.

Here's the script

```
  <script>
    $(".<?php echo strtolower(get_field('code'));?>_btn").click(function(){
        $("#<?php echo strtolower(get_field('code'));?>").on('show', function () {

            $('iframe.fohl-mobile').attr("src","http://www.psfk.com/home#<?php echo get_field('code');?>");

        });
    });
  </script>
```

Here's the whole piece that repeats in the loop

```
 <li>
    <a data-toggle="modal" role="button" class="<?php echo strtolower(get_field('code'));?>_btn" href="#<?php echo strtolower(get_field('code'));?>">&nbsp;</a>

    <img class="lazy" alt="<?php the_title();?>" src="<?php echo site_url('wp-content/fohl/holder.png');?>" data-original="<?php echo site_url('/wp-content/fohl/products/').strtolower(get_field('code'));?>.png" />
    <noscript><img src="<?php echo site_url('/wp-content/fohl/products/').strtolower(get_field('code'));?>.png” alt="<?php the_title();?>"/></noscript>

    <div class="title"><?php the_title();?>

    <div id="<?php echo strtolower(get_field('code'));?>" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <iframe class="fohl-mobile" height="500" width="330" frameborder="0"  src=""></iframe>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(".<?php echo strtolower(get_field('code'));?>_btn").click(function(){
            $("#<?php echo strtolower(get_field('code'));?>").on('show', function () {

                $('iframe.fohl-mobile').attr("src","<?php echo site_url('/home#'.get_field('code'));?>");

            });
        });
    </script>
 </li>
```

Comment: are all of the classes the same?

Comment: Not now but I suppose they could be. The only thing that's really important is that the div id and the url of the iframe src, which are always the same.

Comment: So if we could grab the id from <div id="a1", and use that for the link class, and the src of the iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I added an id to the li and went from there...thanks for the help everyone.

```
 <ul class="products">  
        <?php foreach($products as $post) : setup_postdata($post);?>  
        <li>
            <a data-toggle="modal" role="button" class="this_btn" href="#<?php echo get_field('code');?>">&nbsp;</a>

            <img class="lazy" alt="<?php the_title();?>" src="<?php echo site_url('/wp-content/fohl/holder.png');?>" data-original="<?php echo site_url('/wp-content/fohl/products/').strtolower(get_field('code'));?>.png" />
            <noscript><img src="<?php echo site_url('/wp-content/fohl/products/').strtolower(get_field('code'));?>.png" alt="<?php the_title();?>"/></noscript>

            <p class="title"><?php the_title();?></p>

            <div id="<?php echo get_field('code');?>" class="modal hide fade" class="goat" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <iframe class="fohl-mobile" height="500" width="330" frameborder="0"  src=""></iframe>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    <script>
        $(".this_btn").click(function(){
            var id = $(this).parent().find('div').attr('id');

            $('.modal').on('show', function() {     
                $('.modal iframe.fohl-mobile').attr("src","http://www.website.com/home#"+id);
            });
        });
    </script>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will work for you?  Its untested but conceptually it seems ok.  I would test but you didn't post a JSFiddle.  Basically, your main trigger can be a general class instead of a different class for each iteration of the loop, that references its parent for the more specific internal stuff.

HTML

```
<a data-toggle="modal" role="button" class="class_for_any_btn" href="#<?php echo strtolower(get_field('code'));?>">&nbsp;</a>
```

JS

```
<script>
        $(".class_for_any_btn").click(function(){
            $(this).parent().on('show',"#<?php echo strtolower(get_field('code'));?>", function () {

                $('iframe.fohl-mobile').attr("src","<?php echo site_url('/home#'.get_field('code'));?>");

            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments below, the URL is unique for each <li>, so we could grab the value from the id <div id="a1">, and use that for the link class, and the src of the iframe

Comment: Attach a class to all the divs with ids and then find that class within the parent li and you can get the Id then from that div.  Same process for url.

Comment: Not sure I understand the full process, but if parameters of action are different for each button, you can add a `data-????="___"` attribute to the HTML using PHP, and then reference that in the script. (I'm afraid I don't know the JQuery method for it off the top of my head though)